# How to avoid error "Cannot insert rows out of order" in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm trying to migrate data to QuestDB and inserting historical records, I create table as

```
create table records(
type INT,
interval INT,
timestamp TIMESTAMP,
name STRING) timestamp(timestamp)
```

and insert data from CSV by curl uploading it.

I get back error "Cannot insert rows out of order". I read that out of order was supported in QuestDB but somehow I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert rows out of order on partitioned tables only, create new partitioned table and copy data into it

```
create table records2(
 type INT,
 interval INT,
 timestamp TIMESTAMP,
 name STRING
) 
timestamp(timestamp) partition by DAY

insert into records2
select * from records

drop table records

rename table records2 to records
```

After this you'll be able to insert out of order into table records